# Sql database structure for time based sensor data

Tags: c#, sql, database, vb.net, azure-sql-database

So here is the deal,

I will be dealing with 1 second data that may accumulate for up to a month with up to 40 sensors (columns) this data will be in exactly one second increments and I need to be able to quickly run logic on these sensor data values. So doing the math:

30 days * 24 hours/day * 60 min/hour * 60 sec/min is roughly: 
2.5 million rows x 40 columns is:
100 million data points

Most the data is of double datatype, but I will have booleans, ints, and strings as well. I am entirely new to this so all my ideas on how to handle this are entirely original and therefore they may be absurd and I may be missing the obvious solution. So here are some options I have considered:

1)1 massive table - I am concerned about the performance of this option.

2)DataTables by date, thus reducing the size of an individual table to 86,000 rows.

3)DataTables by hour only dealing with 3600 rows per table, however at that point I start to have an excessive number of tables.

Let me give a little more detail on the nature of the logic - it is entirely sequential, meaning I will start at the beginning and go from the first row all the way to the last. I will essentially be making circles through the data with a number of different algorithms in order to produce my desired results. I am running Sql on Azure. My natural inclination is to move fast and make a lot of mistakes, but in this case I think some experience and advice on how I set up this database will pay off. So, any suggestions?

Comment: I have a few suggestions which are not a qualified answer. You should have one unique key column (no clustered key over severall columns), no nullable columns (thus preventing conversion/null handling in your algorythm), well placed indexes on important columns and depending on your scenario, if you need all the data from one month, keep the data inside one big table. The MSSQL servers are usually better off with optimizing data themselves. After each month you could write the data into an archive table.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I suppose I was nervous about a For each row loop with 2.5M rows, however if there is no issue handling the data quantity, that would by far be the simplest solution.

Comment: If possible you should use select queries for your calculations. Cursors and loops are usually slower.